# Remove Variable(s) in List A if Variable(s) is/are in List B, Python

Tags: python, list

Like the title states I want to remove variables in one list if they happen to be in another list. I have tried various techniques but I can't seem to get a proper code. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: try `set`s and `difference_update`

Comment: By variable do you mean the value of the variables in the list or variable itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use *list comprehension* if you want to maintain the order:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l2 = [1,5,6,3]

>>> [x for x in l if x not in l2]
[2, 4]
```

In case the order of elements in original list don't matter, you may use `set`:

```
>>> list(set(l) - set(l2))
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def returnNewList(a,b):
    h = {}
    for e in b:
        h[e] = True
    return [e for e in a if e not in h]
```

hash table is used to keep the run time complexity linear.

In case list b is sorted then on place of using hash table you can perform binary search, complexity in this case will be nlog(n)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways

```
# just make a new list
[i for i in a if i not in b]

# use sets
list(set(a).difference(set(b)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, however is there a shorter way to write this code?

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b = [0,5,8]
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        a.remove(i)
```

Comment: You shouldn't change the size of a list while iterating over it.

Comment: Thanks, whats the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Take your code and use `a = [0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` or `a = [0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`. Think about what you would expect for `a` as a result and then look what you get. The problem ist the internal pointer to the list. When you remove elements the pointer doesn't move and you might skip some of the remaining elements. (other example: `a = [0, 5, 8]`).